# Some electric component misbehaving

Tags: power-windows, skoda, central-locking, fabia

I have a Skoda Fabia MK2 which is causing some strange issues which I am not able to find the cause for:

1. For some time the electric windows on driver and front passenger (back seat have manual) have worked on and off. Sometimes they worked when I started car, other times they dont work but if I open and close the door, they start working. Now they have stopped working, the window of driver side caused more problems than passenger side. I see that the power window button is illuminated so it seemed to be powered.
2. At the same time the central locking started to act. When I open the door, or close it, it randomly at different time would engage and lock. Sometimes when I unlock it locks immediately. Also it seems like when I lock using the button on panel, it do a double lock (or looks like it lock and then unlock) but its been variable and concerning as if I close door with key inside, it can lock immediately. But, if I lock using the button on panel, the button does not illuminate orange as it would normally do
3. The trunk door sometimes act. Even when car is unlocked it does not open. But if I open the passenger side door and close it, it opens
4. I opened the driver side door as the power windows stopped working while it was half way down. I opened it and slide the window manually. I made sure to fit all wires before closing but now when I open the driver side door, the car does not detect that the door is open (it works for all other doors) and lights dont start.
5. If I use night light (which are manually operated) and forget to turn them off, the car would usually warn with an alarm when I open the driver door to get out. Now it does not. I see that it had some correlation with lock button on panel. When it turn orange when I lock (it seldom do that  now but most of the time car is locked but the button is not illuminated) the alarm also works. But if that button is not working, the alarm fails as well. Central locking works fine however.

Some months ago I had car inspection and I also asked for electrical check. The mechanic told me that the 1) batter is getting old 2) the comfort control unit  is getting old. I see that after this check the problems start to happen. I ordered a second hand comfort control unit but it didnt fix anything. I was hoping it would give some other problems or fix a few but the problems remain the same.

I could be something small, but not sure where the problem could be. Some videos on youtube suggest at changing the lock button inside door on driver side but not sure if all these random issues are all connected with that one thing?

Any ideas would help.

Comment: Asking the wider audience, I'm not fluent in Skoda/VW naming, is the comfort control unit for climate control or is it another name for a body control module?

Comment: Do these problems happen only with the engine on, only with the engine off, or the engine can be on or off? If you have a multimeter have you checked the voltage with the engine on and off?

Comment: @GdD it also called central convenience system/module (CCM). It does control comfort systems like electric windows, interior lighting etc.

Comment: @GdD it happens when the engine is on or off. So if I enter car, sit and close the door, the doors will lock because of this issue. Sometimes they dont, and if I start the engine then it automatically locks (it should not). Same with windows, when they used to work, restarting engine sometimes fixed the windows. Now they dont work at all, or I havent tried alot.

Comment: I suggest you start with checking the voltage on your electrical system both with the engine off and on. A normal system with the engine is about 14 volts, if you have significantly less than that you can get strange issues. It could also be a short or a bad grounding somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Most if not all these function are circuited through the doors. Opening doors and closing doors sometimes has an effect on the issues. This points to worn wiring between the door and body. There will be a rubber boot between the hinge side of the door and the body. Theses contain wires that control these functions. With all of the flexing these wires endure while opening and closing doors, it is common for these to get damaged and short out. Check these wire clusters on both doors and you may very well have found your problem. Using a multimeter can detect problems that can not be seen visually.